# Swift: UIPickerview selecting row-id / Index

Tags: swift, row

im tried to get the selected row-id / Index from the pickerview,
but i get only the name of the selected row.

I've search on the web and documentation without results.

How can i get the ID of the selected row ?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 
**selectedRowInComponent(_:**

I quote from the [UIPickerView Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/selectedRowInComponent:):

> Returns the index of the selected row in a given component.

Comment: thank you this solved my problem.

What i did within: func PickerView(...didSelectRow....){
let selectedID = pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)
println(selectedID)
}